# Optimizing self join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query takes forever to complete. I've added the indexes on all fields included in the `join`, tried putting the `where` conditions into the `join` and I thought I'd ask for advice before tinkering with `FORCE/USE` indexes. It just seems that indexes should be used on both sides of this join. Seems only `i1` is being used.

```
 id select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra

 1  SIMPLE  a   ALL i1,i2,i3                2399303 100.00  Using temporary
 1  SIMPLE  b   ref i1,i2,i3    i1  5   db.a.bt 11996   100.00  Using where


 create index i1 on obs(bt);
 create index i2 on obs(st);
 create index i3 on obs(bt,st);
 create index i4 on obs(sid);

 explain extended
 select distinct b.sid
 from obs a inner join obs b on a.bt = b.bt and a.st = b.st
 where
 a.sid != b.sid and
 abs( datediff( b.sid_start_date , a.sid_expire_date ) ) < 60;
```

I've tried both `ALTER TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` above to add indexes to `obs`.

Comment: Did you try this with a simple join (from obs a,obs b where ...) to see if it is faster?

Comment: I've removed the `INNER JOIN` and used the suggested syntax, putting all conditions in `WHERE` and got the same `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` output.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not selecting any of the columns in table a, it may be better to use an exists. An exists allows you to check if the information you are looking for is in a specified table without using a join. Removing the join improves the performance. I also like exists because I think it makes the query easier to understand when you come back to it months later.

```
select distinct b.sid
 from obs b
 where exists (Select 1
                From obs a
                Where a.bt = b.bt
                 and a.st = b.st
                 and a.sid != b.sid
                 and abs( datediff( b.sid_start_date , a.sid_expire_date ) ) < 60);
```